# Crystal Reports 2008: Suppress Group Header when a specific range date is not included

Tags: crystal-reports

Please help me to apply a Suppress Group Header when the report does not include a range date between 04-May-15 to 18-May-15.

I want groups "100014" and "100044" to hide and group "100020" (has date range 04-May-15 to 18-May-15) to show in the report. See the following to understand my question. Thank you for your help.

*Before Suppress:*

---

```
Item Code   Item Name    Quantity    Release Date    Due Date
---------   ---------    --------    ------------    --------
  100014    abmnbofg         11       15-Jun-13      19-Jul-15
  100014    abertyyi          4       04-Aug-14      18-Sep-14
  100014    abdwsefg          3       12-Feb-13      20-Nov-14
  100014    abvghefg          2       17-Mar-15      28-Apr-15

  100020    abcgdefg         11       05-Jun-12      23-Jul-15
  100020    abcdefug          9       04-May-15      18-May-15 ****
  100020    abscdefg          4       30-May-14      18-Jan-15
  100020    abcdsefg          3       13-Nov-13      23-Oct-14
  100020    abcdoefg          2       07-May-15      18-May-15

  100044    abwdefgs         11       13-Feb-12      13-Feb-15
  100044    abcdefug          9       05-Feb-13      18-Mar-14
  100044    abseweza          4       20-Mar-14      18-Apr-15
  100044    abcasdfg          3       23-Oct-13      08-Nov-14
  100044    abcdoeuy          2       17-Apr-11      19-Apr-15
```

*After Suppress: Group 100020 shows in the report and group "100014" and "100044" are hiding.*

---

```
Item Code   Item Name    Quantity    Release Date    Due Date
---------   ---------    --------    ------------    --------
  100020    abcgdefg         11       05-Jun-12      23-Jul-15
  100020    abcdefug          9       04-May-15      18-May-15 ****
  100020    abscdefg          4       30-May-14      18-Jan-15
  100020    abcdsefg          3       13-Nov-13      23-Oct-14
  100020    abcdoefg          2       07-May-15      18-May-15
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Try below way.

Take any date for example purpose I am taking `Release Date` and assuming required field is date. If this is not the format then take required format in your formula

In `supress` of the header click on `x-2` and write below formula:

```
if (Release Date = 04-May-15 or Release Date = 05-May-15 or Release Date = 06-May-15 or Release Date = 07-May-15 or Release Date = 08-May-15 or Release Date = 09-May-15 or Release Date = 10-May-15 or Release Date = 11-May-15 or Release Date = 12-May-15 or Release Date = 13-May-15 or Release Date = 14-May-15 or Release Date = 15-May-15 or Release Date = 16-May-15 or Release Date = 17-May-15 or Release Date = 18-May-15)
Then False
Else True
```